# Regarding to backward of convolution layer in Deep learning

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I understood the way to compute the forward part in Deep learning. Now, I want to understand the backward part. Let's take `X(2,2)` as an example. The backward at the position `X(2,2)` can compute as the figure bellow

[image]

My question is that where is `dE/dY` (such as `dE/dY(1,1)`,`dE/dY(1,2)`...) in the formula? How to compute it at the first iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

Those terms are in the final expansion at the bottom of the slide; they contribute to the summation for dE/dX(2,2).  In your first back-propagation, you start at the end and work backwards (hence the name) -- and the **Y** values are the ground-truth labels.  So much for computing them.  :-)

**LONG ANSWER**

I'll keep this in more abstract, natural-language terms.  I'm hopeful that the alternate explanation will help you see the large picture as well as sorting out the math.

You start the training with assigned weights that may or may not be at all related to the ground truth (labels).  You move blindly forward, making predictions at each layer based on naive faith in those weights.  The Y(i,j) values are the resulting meta-pixels from that faith.

Then you hit the labels at the end.  You work backward, adjusting each weight.  Note that, at the last layer, the **Y** values are the ground-truth labels.

At each layer, you mathematically deal with two factors:

1. How far off was this prediction?
2. How heavily did this parameter contribute to that prediction?

You adjust the X-to-Y weight by "off * weight * learning_rate".
When you complete that for layer N, you back up to layer N-1 and repeat.

**PROGRESSION**

Whether you initialize your weights with fixed or random values (I generally recommend the latter), you'll notice that there's really not much progress in the early iterations.  Since this is slow adjustment from guess-work weights, it takes several iterations to get a glimmer of useful learning into the last layers.  The first layers are still cluelessly thrashing at this point.  The loss function will bounce around close to its initial values for a while.  For instance, with GoogLeNet's image recognition, this flailing lasts for about 30 epochs.

Then, finally, you get some valid learning in the latter layers, the patterns stabilize enough that some consistency percolates back to the early layers.  At this point, you'll see the loss function drop to a "directed experimentation" level.  From there, the progression depends a lot on the paradigm and texture of the problem: some have a sharp drop, then a gradual convergence; others have a more gradual drop, almost an exponential decay to convergence; more complex topologies have additional sharp drops as middle or early phases "get their footing".

Comment: Thank Prune. I do not think `Y` is ground truth label. It is output of convolution layer as `Y=conv(X,kernel)`, or mathematics as `Y=W.X`. Hence, apply chain rule `dE/dX=dE/dY x dY/dX=dE/dY x W`, where E is loss function at last layer. To compute `dE/dY`, I think we need to apply the chain rule again to express it. But in caffe tool, I saw it using the `diff` term. I am not sure what I am understand. You can saw the lecture at https://1drv.ms/p/s!ArG9tn58GyvBge5DZXYiy3Wj39k4Ew   and  https://1drv.ms/p/s!ArG9tn58GyvBge5JDI_SkvbMBiMEiQ

Comment: I've been through the course.  :-)  My point is that in the first layer of back-prop, the ground truth *is* the prediction.  Thereafter, every layer computes the values by applying the chain rule to the one after, so we always have those values from the previous back-prop application.  Does that clear it up, or do I need to find time to watch the lecture and re-define the symbology in my head?

Comment: No. You are right. I just misunderstand your point. I looked at the Convolution layer source code and analysis it with mathematic. Let's see it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995536/from-mathematics-equations-to-programming-of-convolution-in-caffe